# Rollup modules but keep all variables global

Tags: javascript, global-variables, es6-modules, rollup, rollupjs

I will simplify code for my problem. So let's assume I have in `module1.js`

```js
export class MyClass { };
```

and in `index.js`

```js
import { MyClass } from './module1.js'

var X = MyClass();
```

Next i want to bundle `index.js` with *rollup* in such way that the result file contents should look like this

```js
class MyClass { };
var X = MyClass();
```

My goal is to put the result file into `script` tag and to be able to access all declared variables in global space e.g `window.MyClass` and `window.X` from other scripts.

Is there any rollup options or plugins for this purpose?

Comment: `MyClass` and `X` are not global variables, they are in module scopes - and rollup will preserve this property. Rollup also will not guarantee that the names of these variables will stay the same when you bundle multiple modules. You should not rely on anything there. Either explicitly assign them to globals, or just don't use globals at all and properly export/import them to where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

In the Rollup configuration, you can set [output.format](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-format) to `iife`:

> A self-executing function, suitable for inclusion as a `<script>` tag. (If you want to create a bundle for your application, you probably want to use this.). "iife" stands for "immediately-invoked Function Expression"

This should give you exactly what you want, except that iifes scope their variables (it's actually why they are used), so your variables will still not end up in the global scope.

But you can either remove the surrounding function invocation (i.e. `(function(){` on top and `})()` at the end), or you explicitly put the variables you need into global scope by assigning them to the `window` object:

```
window.X = MyClass();
```

The latter might be the cleaner approach, since you don't have to edit the bundled output, it is more obvious what you do, and it allows you to select what should be global.

Does that work for you?

Comment: yeah I already thought about removing iife wrappers with some plugins but this approach feels wrong and Im looking for cleaner solution
The problem is I already have a lot of files with a lot of vars and also a lot of references to this vars from global scope so it is impossible to refactor to manual assignments to window object. 
I want to turn this files to modules style but keeping vars global